# Deleting text in a directory

Tags: 14.04, server

By mistake, i added the content of the file in my directory now when ever i am typing ls it is showing all the words with files in my current directory. i want to delete this word from my directory.[image]

I have a folder named controller and when i typed ls command it is showing the above screenshot. You can see that there are number of unwanted files which are visible apart of WalletController.php so i want to delete all those text from the current folder except WalletController.php

Comment: Its not clear to me what you have meant..

Comment: in the above screenshot you can see there are files walletcontroller.php and there are some text too like "Your profile has been dissapproved" . i want to delete the later part.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Post the text and apply code formatting. Provide sample output if your problem involves text processing.

Comment: Do all of these garbage files have length 0? (try `ls -l`). In that case, you could use a `find` command to find and delete all these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This text is just file names, and you can delete it like any other file, for example

```
rm 'Your profile has been dissapproved successfully,'
```

You can use

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type f -not -name \*.php -exec rm -i {} \;
```

to remove all but the .php files. Without the `-maxdepth 1` it will remove them in all subdirectories, too. Without the `-i` it will remove the files without asking.

Comment: Thanks it is working, is there any command to delete all files except .php file?

Comment: Added that to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

To remove all files except `WalletController.php`, from that directory:

```
shopt -s extglob; rm !(WalletController.php)
```

Or

```
GLOBIGNORE=WalletController.php; rm *
```